# Displaying a matplotlib bar chart in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, tkinter

I am trying to display a matplotlib bar chart in a Tkinter window. I have found plenty of tutorials on how to put a line chart in, such as this:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html

But I can't find one for putting in a bar chart. The only way I know to make a bar chart is like this: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html. Obviously, the modules imported in the bar chart example are not the same as the ones in the Tkinter examples, and I'm not sure how to make it work, if it can at all.

Long story short, can anyone provide me with an example of a matplotlib bar chart being displayed inside a Tkinter window? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sam, could you add what you've tried so far? It seems like you just need to have a go at bodging together the two links you've given, why not have a go!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone who may be wondering in the future, I figured out how to get it to work. Basically, your bar chart has to be on a Figure so that FigureCanvasTkAgg can then generate a widget for Tkinter to use. I had assumed that you needed to use pyplot, which isn't true. This is what I came up with:

```
import matplotlib, numpy, sys
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()

f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

data = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)

ind = numpy.arange(5)  # the x locations for the groups
width = .5

rects1 = ax.bar(ind, data, width)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Apparently since ~2018, `canvas.draw()` has replaced `canvas.show()` -- I edited the code accordingly. See https://github.com/jarvisteach/appJar/issues/551